# Differences and effects of brake lever offset

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

I've seen some flat bar brake levers where the the pivoting plane of the lever blade is offset and not in line with the center of the handlebar's cross section.

What's the purpose for such design? Are there any effects or noticeable feeling between a centered-blade design and an offset-blade design? Is it done for optimization in hydraulic brakes?

Comment: Have you seen these on drop bar or flat bar bikes?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Flat bars. I've seen the offset brake blades on the new Shimano MTB brake levers and some off-brand brakes from various other entry-level MTBs.

Comment: This design moves the lever in the direction of the palm of the cyclist, making the grip more comfortable and effective.